# JQuery drag and drop responsiveness

Tags: jquery, responsive

I am creating a drag and drop application with jquery drag and drop.
I want to make the elements dragged over a droppable target to be responsive.
How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Refer those urls

[droppable](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/)

[draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/)

Answer (score 0):

See if this is what you're looking for.

```js
(function($) {
  $("#sortable").sortable();
  $("#sortable").disableSelection();
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background: #DDD;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 12px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}  

#sortable {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }

  #sortable li {
    margin: 0 3px 3px 3px;
    padding: 5px;
    line_height: 8px;
    padding-left: 1.5em;
    font-size: 1.4em;
  }
  
  #sortable li span {
    position: relative;
    left: -30px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">

  <ul id="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```